# QT C++, Call a function in main from a child hierarchies

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently developing software that requires this architecture:

Main Program -> OpcClient -> NodeConveyor -> NodeLoad

Knowing that in the Main I create a single Client.
When the Client is created he creates xx NodeConveyors.
Each NodeConveyor created creates xx NodeLoads.

Once the NodeLoad created I check some parameters and I would like if some are not good, transmit a signal to a slot of the Main in order to display it in a QPlainText of the ui_mainwindow.

For that I created a Signal in the class NodeLoad which is connected to a Slot in the class NodeConveyor. The slot of the class NodeConveyor emits a signal connected to a slot of the class OpcClient. The slot of the class OpcClient emits a signal connected to a slot of the Main Program.

However, when I test, only the connection between the signal of the class OpcClient and the slot of the main program work.

I am working on Qt 5.12.3 with the MinGW 7.3.0 32 bit compiler

-----NodeLoad Class-----

```
NodeLoad::NodeLoad(QOpcUaClient* client, int x, int y,QString opcNameSpace)
{
    if(QOpcUa::BadNodeIdUnknown) emit NodeIdError_Signal();
}
```

-----NodeConveyor Class-----

```
NodeConveyor::NodeConveyor(QOpcUaClient* client,int x,QString opcNameSpace)
{
    for(int y(0);y<1;y++)
    {
        Load[y] = new NodeLoad(client,x,y,opcNameSpace);
        connect(Load[y],SIGNAL(NodeIdError_Signal()),this,SLOT  (ConveyorIdError_Slot()));
    }
}
void NodeConveyor::ConveyorIdError_Slot()
{
    emit ConveyorIdError_Signal();
}
```

-----OPC_CLient Class-----

```
OPC_Client::OPC_Client(QString ServerUrl): m_servUrl(ServerUrl)
{
    for(int i(0);i<nbConveyors;i++)
    {
        conveyor[i] = new NodeConveyor(m_client,i,"ns=2;");
        connect(conveyor[i],SIGNAL(ConveyorIdError_Signal()),this,SLOT(ClientIdError_Slot()));
    }
}
void OPC_Client::ClientIdError_Slot()
{
    emit ClientIdError_Signal();
}
```

-----OPC_Main Class-----

```
OPC_Main::OPC_Main(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::OPC_Main),
{
    OPC_client = new OPC_Client("opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49320");
    connect(OPC_client,SIGNAL(ClientIdError_Signal()),this,SLOT(IdError_Slot()));
}
void iMPRESS_OPC_Main::IdError_Slot()
{
    ui->mLog->appendHtml(QTime::currentTime().toString("h:mm:ss ") + "<font color=\"Red\">" + " - Error Tag Names doesn't match");
}
```

Currently, only when I make a emit clientIdError_Signal (); directly from OPC_Client :: OPC_Client ... the message is displayed.

Anyone have some idea for my problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome! What's this supposed to mean: `if(QOpcUa::BadNodeIdUnknown)`? Is this the actual code? If not, please provide a  [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You connect signals and slots after emitting. I mean when signal emits (in constructor) no connection exists. Try emit signal after connection (not in constructor but in some method like `NodeLoad::CheckForErrors()` which you will call after constructor). Something like this

```
NodeConveyor::NodeConveyor(QOpcUaClient* client,int x,QString opcNameSpace)
{
    for(int y(0);y<1;y++)
    {
        Load[y] = new NodeLoad(client,x,y,opcNameSpace);
        connect(Load[y],SIGNAL(NodeIdError_Signal()),this,SLOT  (ConveyorIdError_Slot()));
        Load[y]->CheckForErrors();
    }
}

void NodeLoad::CheckForErrors()
{
    if(QOpcUa::BadNodeIdUnknown) emit NodeIdError_Signal();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes thanks, that's what I realized yesterday. I emit the signal to the construction of the object, or the signal connection is made after construction.

And is there a method to connect directly the Signal of NodeConveyor to a Slot in the main ?

I already improve the program by directly connecting the signals between them. And I deleted the intermediate slots.